# Change Dropdown attributes using internal css

Tags: html, css

Here's the current internal HTML and CSS I currently have. I want to make the box slightly bigger than it is, and I want to change the background color of the box to the cream color currently in the CSS.

```css
select option {
  width: 30%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #fff2e2;
  color: #56515d;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<select id="typeofservice" name="typeofservice">
  <option value="value1">Dine In</option>
  <option value="value2">Carry Out</option>
  <option value="value3">Delivery</option>
</select>
```

Comment: remove the height and make it direct css for select without using option element

Comment: also you can learn more about CSS properties through this [CSS Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the appeal like this:

```
select {
...
}
```

Also, set the `height: auto` to remove the height limitation.

```css
select {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff2e2;
  color: #56515d;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<select id="typeofservice" name="typeofservice">
  <option value="value1">Dine In</option>
  <option value="value2">Carry Out</option>
  <option value="value3">Delivery</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean was such a result necessary?

Comment: @LaurenTownsend, I wanted to make sure that when you run the snippet of my answer, you get the result you want.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. What would be the css code to make changes to a radio button grouping?

Comment: @LaurenTownsend, If we talk about a radio button, then the appeal is - `input[type=radio] { styles }`